# Python to filter a comma-separated list on another csv list

Tags: python

I have two strings:

```
s1 = "Brendon, Melissa, Jason, , McGuirk" #the gauranteed string in format "x, y, z"
s2 = "brandon,melissa,jxz  ,paula,coach" #the messy string
```

and would like to create a Python (2.7) list that uses the value in l1 if it exists, otherwise pass through the value in l2.  I have working code, but even with the list comprehensions, I feel like there may be a more Pythonic way of doing this.  Any ideas what that might be?

```
l1 = [x.strip() for x in s1.split(',')]
l2 = [x.strip() for x in s2.split(',')]
f = lambda s: s[1] if s[1] else s[0]
final = [f(x) for x in zip(l2, l1)]
```

The list "final" now contains:

```
['Brendon', 'Melissa', 'Jason', 'paula', 'McGuirk']
```

Which is correct.

------- edit
So, looking at Jon's answer below, a or b seems like the simplest, most readable approach.  I moved the string cleaning to a small function, and ended up with this.  Any further improvements to make?

```
trim_csv = lambda csv: [s.strip() for s in csv.split(',')]
print [a or b for a, b in zip(trim_csv(s1), trim_csv(s2))]
```

Comment: What if there's missing values in both s1 and s2? The two answers I see as of this posting return a length-4 list (ie they drop it).

Comment: @Spacedman They don't drop it - they keep the element as `''`

Comment: Not if there's no space between the commas - probably because you split on "comma-space"

Comment: @Spacedman And it'll only return a 1-list if the delimiter isn't even present... If the input format changes - expect the results to change ;)

Comment: Yeah, we can't second-guess the OPs input format...

Comment: Oh, FYI, the second list is always guaranteed to have no blank strings.  They may be garbage, but there's something there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for your example

```
s1 = "Brendon, Melissa, Jason, , McGuirk"
s2 = "brandon, melissa, jxz, paula, coach"

print [a or b for a, b in zip(s1.split(', '), s2.split(', '))]
```

Slightly more generic one that can be adapated:

```
import re
from itertools import izip_longest, ifilter, imap

s1 = "Brendon, Melissa, Jason, , McGuirk"
s2 = "brandon, melissa, jxz, paula, coach"


def take_first_not_empty(*args):
    splitter = re.compile(r'\s*?,\s*').split
    words = imap(splitter, args)
    return [next(ifilter(None, vals), '') for vals in izip_longest(*words, fillvalue='')]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the usage of your generic example.  I tried: [take_first_not_empty(a, b) for a, b in zip(s1.split(', '), s2.split(', '))]
And it returned a list of items as individual lists.  e.g.:
[['Brendon'], ['Melissa'], ['Jason'], ['paula'], ['McGuirk']]

Comment: @Phil use it as `take_first_not_empty(s1, s2)`

Comment: Oh!  That's pretty cool.  I'm pretty terrible at reading regex...  can it be modified to handle strings that don't split on comma-space?  er, or rather to trim the whitespace from dirty strings (that might have been assembled from a string that ended in useless whitespace).

Comment: @Phil yup - it will split on comma whether preceded or followed by space as it is at the moment - so it's relatively flexible, but fairly straightforward to tweak to your requirements

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
>>> s1 = "Brendon, Melissa, Jason, , McGuirk"
>>> s2 = "brandon, melissa, jxz, paula, coach"
>>> [x if x else y  for x,y in zip( s1.split(', '),s2.split(', '))]
['Brendon', 'Melissa', 'Jason', 'paula', 'McGuirk']
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can count on the lists always being separated comma-space.  I will update the question.